# How do I select my race when playing ranked games in Company of Heroes?

Tags: company-of-heroes

I enjoy playing CoH ranked games, but apparently I always get assigned a random race. Is there a way to select which faction I want to play with?

Comment: Race? You mean you want to be an Aryan rather than those damn Yanks?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what it is called like in CoH, I've been a WC3 player for ages and everybody always called it "race".

Comment: A "race" because it's a fantasy game, in real life based combat games they are called factions.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not a native English speaker so I didn't know.

Comment: @mafutrct - Sorry about that... I am not usually such a jerk.

Comment: @Chaos No worries, I'm glad I learned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out myself by now. It is actually both possible and easy. Instead of hitting "Play" at the top of the screen, select "Multiplayer" - "Ranked game". This screen allows you to set up team settings (1vs1, 2vs2, AT, ...) as well as your faction and the possible maps. Now hit "Play" at the bottom right of the screen.